# Can't use operator<< with std::float128_t; how do I print it?

Tags: c++, x86-64, iostream, c++23, stdfloat

I have the following code, which doesn't compile with x86_64 GCC 13:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdfloat>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::float128_t{1} << '\n';
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:5:15: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'std::float128_t' {aka '_Float128'})
    5 |     std::cout << std::float128_t{1} << '\n';
      |     ~~~~~~~~~ ^~      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |          |            |
      |          |            std::float128_t {aka _Float128}
      |          std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}
```

The listed ambiguous overloads are:

- `operator<<(long)`
- `operator<<(unsigned long)`
- `operator<<(bool)`
- ...

Surprisingly, `operator<<(float)` and other floating point types aren't listed.

I've checked the compiler support page for C++23, and this feature *should* be supported:

| C++23 features | Paper(s) | libstdc++ | libc++ | MVSV STL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Standard names and library support for extended floating-point types | [P1467R9](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1467r9.html) | 13 |  | 19.37** |

*See [C++23 compiler support page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/23)*

Am I misunderstanding something? Is cppreference wrong and extended floating-point types aren't fully supported yet?
**How do I print a `std::float128_t` without third-party libraries?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### `operator<<(std::float128_t)` is optional

None of the `operator<<` overloads for extended floating-point types from `<stdfloat>` are guaranteed to exist. For `std::float128_t` it is quite common that this isn't the case.
On x86_64:

- `long double` is typically an 80-bit floating point type, and
- `std::float128_t` is a quadruple precision IEEE-754 floating-point type.

This means that `std::float128_t` has a greater conversion rank<sup>1)</sup> than `long double`.
As a result, `operator<<(std::float128_t)` is optional:

> Otherwise, if the floating-point conversion rank of extended-floating-point-type is **less than or equal to that of long double**, the formatting conversion occurs as if it performed the following code fragment:
>
> ```cpp
> bool failed = use_facet<num_put<charT, ostreambuf_iterator<charT, traits>>>(getloc()).put(*this, *this, fill(), static_cast<long double>(val)).failed();
> ```
>
> **Otherwise, an invocation of the operator function is conditionally supported with implementation-defined semantics.**

- [[ostream.formatted]/[ostream.inserters.arithmetic] §5](https://eel.is/c++draft/ostream.formatted#ostream.inserters.arithmetic-5)

GCC isn't required to support it, and you should consider alternatives to `operator<<` when printing extended floating point types.

### Alternatives

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdfloat>
#include <format>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::format("{}", std::float128_t{1}) << '\n';
}
```

This solution currently works, and is guaranteed to work.
The `std::formatter` for extended floating-point types is implemented using `std::to_chars`, which is required to support all arithmetic types.

```cpp
#include <print>
#include <stdfloat>

int main() {
    std::println("{}", std::float128_t{1});
}
```

This solution doesn't work yet because libstdc++ doesn't implement the `<print>` header yet.
However, once it does, this will also work, because `std::println` also uses `std::formatter`.

### If `std::format` works, why is `operator<<` not supported?

The proposal paper answers this question:

> The streaming operators use the virtual functions `num_put<>::do_put` and `num_get<>::do_get` for output and input of arithmetic types. To fully and properly support extended floating-point types, new virtual functions would need to be added. That would be an ABI break. While an ABI break is not out of the question, it would have strong opposition. This proposal is not worth the effort that would be necessary to get an ABI break through the committee.

- [P1467r9 §iostream](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1467r9.html#iostream)

---

<sup>1)</sup> The conversion rank is greater because `std::float128_t` can represent more values than `long double`, see [[conv.rank] §2](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.rank#2).

Answer (score 2):

The old school solution is libquadmath, which comes with GCC by default.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <quadmath.h>

int main()
{
    __float128 x = 12.3; // `__float128` should be equivalent to `std::float128_t`.
    char buf[200];
    quadmath_snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%Qf", x);
    std::cout << buf << '\n';
}
```

Add `-lquadmath` when linking.

Comment: `__float128` and `std::float128_t/_Float128` have the same representation, but they are distinct types. `quadmath_snprintf` is documented to convert `__float128`, so you might need to cast a `std::float128_t` to `__float128` when using it to avoid getting compiler warnings or worse.

Comment: @JanSchultke `std::is_same_v` says `__float128` and `_Float128` are the same, and I don't get warnings with `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: Really? I've tested this using `std::is_same_v` myself, and it's not the same type: https://godbolt.org/z/eWYTPnGzr

Comment: @JanSchultke Hmm, they are different starting from GCC 13.

Comment: @JanSchultke `quadmath_snprintf` doesn't seem to have compile-time warnings for the format string. It's not entirely clear from [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Floating-Types.html), but I'm guessing they'll always have the same representation?

Comment: I'm not sure how you've tested the assertion before GCC 13. For me, `_Float128` doesn't exist in GCC 12, so I wasn't able to make the assertion compile. `_Float128` needs to be IEEE-754, and for `__float128` you can always `static_assert(std::numeric_limits<__float128>::is_iec559);` to be on the safe side. Or to be extra safe, explicitly cast between the two types everywhere. Even if the representations are identical, type punning in `printf` family functions is usually UB.

Comment: @JanSchultke Ah, `quadmath.h` was defining `_Float128`.