# Can I use std-stream for the C++23 extended floating point types?

Tags: c++, floating-point, std, c++23

I found the interesting *extended floating point* types in C++23 at  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/floating-point. My *g++ 13.2* has no overload for

```cpp
   std::cout << 0.1f128;
```

Is this intentional (by the standard) or just a missing feature in g++ right now?

---

This is my code:

```cpp
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

#include <stdfloat>

using namespace std;

template <typename Float>
void show(const char* name, const Float example) {
    cout << name << " with 0.1:" << example << '\n';
    cout << "  digits10 = " << numeric_limits<Float>::digits10 << '\n';
    cout << "  max_digits10 = " << numeric_limits<Float>::max_digits10 << '\n';
    cout << "  min_exponent10 = " << numeric_limits<Float>::min_exponent10 << '\n';
    cout << "  max_exponent10 = " << numeric_limits<Float>::max_exponent10 << '\n';
    cout << "  min() = " << numeric_limits<Float>::min() << '\n';
    cout << "  max() = " << numeric_limits<Float>::max() << '\n';
    cout << "  epsilon() = " << numeric_limits<Float>::epsilon() << '\n';
    cout << "  round_error() = " << numeric_limits<Float>::round_error() << '\n';
    cout << "  denorm_min() = " << numeric_limits<Float>::denorm_min() << '\n';
}
#define SHOW(ftype,example) show<ftype>(#ftype, example)

int main() {
    SHOW(float, 0.1f);
    SHOW(double, 0.1);
    SHOW(long double, 0.1l);
    SHOW(std::float16_t, 0.1f16);
    SHOW(std::float32_t, 0.1f32);
    SHOW(std::float64_t, 0.1f64);
    // SHOW(std::float128_t, 0.1f128);  // <<< missing
    SHOW(std::bfloat16_t, 0.1bf16);
}
```

This my makefile rule:

```
CXX23FLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -std=c++23 -lpthread -pthread -Wno-missing-field-initializers -g -fext-numeric-literals

CXX:=docker run --rm -i -t --volume $(CURDIR):/workdir --workdir /workdir gcc:13.2 g++

%.x: %.23.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXX23FLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Comment: The standard does require the appropriate overloads for extended floating-point types, see [`[ostream.general]`](https://eel.is/c++draft/ostream.general).

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't say what the result should be if the type is wider than `long double` [Arithmetic inserters](http://eel.is/c++draft/ostream.formatted#ostream.inserters.arithmetic-5)  ... *"conditionally supported with implementation-defined semantics."*

Comment: I found it myself. As @BoP says, its not guaranteed to be wider then long double. But _if_ it is https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1467r9.html#iostream says, that is is _not_ supported by streams. Do I read this right, @heap_underrun?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. Thanks, @BoP for reading further than just declarations. Anyway, this question seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76500128/1458097

Comment: @heapunderrun Indeed it does. Thanks. I voted to close the question as dup.

Comment: Not all types are required by the standard, especially if they are not supported by hardware.  float128 is not supported by x86 hardware..